# Angular Filter by multiple Checkboxes and properties issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter with few properties of a json output in Angular.js, here is my [plunker](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/oDkyyjTVmElpbeB9sEt5?p=preview) link.

The actual problem is, if i am trying to filter by type 1, than it automatically color filter value is also get checked, i want both filters should be applied separately or combined.

I want this filter to be applied on a e-commerce site for selecting the brands, category, minimum and maximum price etc.

How should this filter function should be written in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `checked` property and `ng-model` in **both** different types of checkboxs

```
ng-checked="person.checked" ng-model="person.checked"
```

Instead you should use two different models for example `person.checked.type` and `person.checked.color`, should be something like:

```
//in type checks
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="person.checked.type" ng-model="person.checked.type"/> {{ person.type }} 

//in color checks
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="person.checked.color" ng-model="person.checked.color" {{ person.color }}
```

**Update**

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdFXvF?p=preview) is a working plunker

Comment: after updating, even filter thing is also not working,

Comment: I added to the answer  an updated plunker it's working fine, off course you also need to update your filters logic

Comment: I updated your plunker it's working fine, off course you also need to update your filters logic

Comment: What was the issue, so that i can understand it better, do some thing more advanced with filter?

Comment: Nope, each filter should have it's own "filtered" condition